# How to create Nodes out of segmentation Mask of Objects in an image

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, python, image-processing, geometric-deep-learning

I am new to geometric deep learning. I am trying to use GNN to create nodes based on the objects present in an image. However, most of the online resources refer to creating nodes equivalent to the pixels of the image. However, what am looking for is to define objects in image as nodes meaning if I have a car, this should be a node and a pedestrian should be another node. How can I do that and How can I define the adjacency matrix between them.

Comment: It's been a while since I read anything on GDL. However, one idea that comes to my mind (please, at least cite me if you get millions with these ideas :P) is to first pre-detect the objects with some existing object detector, but you need that, which you may not have. Alternatively, you may use some kind of clustering.